# How to set background-image url with vue bind

Tags: vue.js

I have a vue component that is used based on a items array. The array contains all the relevant information needed in the component. The issues is with setting the background-image url. I only managed to make it work by giving it the whole css syntax instead of just a image url. How can I make it work only with an image url?

```
<div id="app">
  <book
  v-for="item in items"
  v-bind:item="item"
    ></book>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script>
Vue.component('book', {
  props: ['item'],
  template: '<div class="book" :class=" item.itemClass "><a :href="item.link" class="card"><div class="thumb" :style="item.url"></div><article><h1>{{  item.titlu }}</h1><span>{{ item.autor }}</span></article></a></div>'
})
var vueApp = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        items: [
            {
                itemClass: 'item-1',
                titlu: 'Title 1',
                autor: 'Author 1',
                link: 'www.google.com',
                url: 'background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/flex-1.jpg);',
            },
            {
                itemClass: 'item-2',
                titlu: 'Title 2',
                autor: 'Author 2',
                link: 'www.google.com',
                url: 'background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/flex-1.jpg)',
            },
            {
                itemClass: 'item-2',
                titlu: 'Title 3',
                autor: 'Author 3',
                link: 'www.google.com',
                url: 'background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/flex-1.jpg);',
            },                      
        ]
    },
})
</script>
```

Comment: did you get your answer?

Comment: Ok so most of the answers are just just partial answers to the problem. Sure I can use backgroundImage and set the url, but it doesn't work as expected for local images, it works only with links. Maybe this wasn't part of the question per se, but I'd like a css image-background solution that just works as it should, not tricks that work 50%.

Comment: Then you need to pass the correct path to the URL. if you add an example of where you have added local images, anyone can help here for sure. But the details are mandatory and Not sure who has downvoted every answer.

Comment: I didn't vote or down vote any answer, dunno why they are down voted.

Answer (score 3):

[Inline styles binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles) requires *an object* or *array of objects*, whereas you're passing *a string*.

Its form should be:

```js
:style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(...)' }"
```

Comment: In particular this works: `<span v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + image.url + ')' }"></span>`. Do not forget to put spaces before and after `+`.

Answer (score -1):

Use bellow code.

```
<div id="app">
        <book v-for="item in items" v-bind:item="item"></book>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script>
        Vue.component('book', {
            props: ['item'],
            template: `<div class="book" :class=" item.itemClass "><a :href="item.link" class="card"><div class="thumb" :style="{background: 'url('+item.url+')'}"></div><article><h1>{{  item.titlu }}</h1><span>{{ item.autor }}</span></article></a></div>`

        })
        var vueApp = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                items: [{
                        itemClass: 'item-1',
                        titlu: 'Title 1',
                        autor: 'Author 1',
                        link: 'www.google.com',
                        url: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/flex-1.jpg',
                    },
                    {
                        itemClass: 'item-2',
                        titlu: 'Title 2',
                        autor: 'Author 2',
                        link: 'www.google.com',
                        url: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/flex-1.jpg',
                    },
                    {
                        itemClass: 'item-2',
                        titlu: 'Title 3',
                        autor: 'Author 3',
                        link: 'www.google.com',
                        url: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/flex-1.jpg',
                    },
                ]
            },
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Bind the url to the style attribute

```
<div class="book" :class=" item.itemClass " :style="item.url">
```

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/nicolai_lebek/g6k3v49f/3/